# jQuery .css, how to translate it into Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, properties

I have the following jQuery code:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {


      setTimeout(function() {
        $('.green.bar .inner').css('width', '20%')
      },1000);


    });
</script>
```

And the html is:

```
<div class="green bar">
<div class="inner" style="width:10%"></div>
</div>
```

How can I do what the jQuery code does using just JavaScript?

Thanks a lot

Comment: That is JavaScript code.

Comment: Just give in and come to the dark side. Don't make your life more difficult by trying to do something that jQuery already does for you.

Comment: I think he means "without jQuery" when he says "just JavaScript". And honestly, I use jQuery exactly so I don't have to write this in plain javascript.

Comment: Ugh. All these *"jQuery is JavaScript"* comments that get posted on SO are just pedantic noise. The intent is simple and clear. How to accomplish this without the jQuery abstraction from the native API. Goodness.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you mean without using jQuery:

```
// If you only want to operate on the first match
setTimeout(function(){
    document.querySelector('.green.bar .inner').style.width = '20%';
});
```

Or:

```
// If you want to operate on all matches
setTimeout(function(){
    var elements = document.querySelectorAll('.green.bar .inner');
    for(e in elements){
        elements[e].style.width = '20%';
    }
});
```

Comment: To the OP, keep in mind this will work in most browsers, but in the IE world, IE8 and above. Specifically those that support the W3C Selectors API